# How to do video conversion in php using ffmpeg?

Tags: php, codeigniter, video, ffmpeg, codeigniter-2

I am using ffmpeg to convert any video to mp4.

I am using this command in my php script to convert video:

```
echo exec("/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i $inputFile -c:v libx264 -strict experimental $outputFile");

$inputFile  = DOC_ROOT. "media/video/tmp/{$postId}_v.{$ext}";
$outputFile  = DOC_ROOT. "media/video/{$postId}_v.mp4";
```

But, somehow, it's not converting the video. What could be the reason?

> Is there any option to change another method or is there any
>   particular library add to the codeigniter?

Comment: Are the variables `$inputFile` and `$outputFile` initialized before you launch the command?

Comment: We know what is doesn't do. Do you mind telling us what it does do? Does it crash? is there an error message? Is your computer turned on?

Comment: If you run the command manually, does it work? How long does it take? The obvious thing to me would be that you're getting a timeout, video conversion isn't something I'd launch from a PHP script (I'd expect the file to still produce unless child processes are killed on timeout, but the PHP page to timeout, and not load). If not this, then I'd expect some error to be displayed or logged.

Answer (score 1):

Use shell_exe for linux:

```
shell_exec("ffmpegPath  -i sample.mov-s 1280x720 -metadata title='Sample' -bufsize 1835k -b:v 1000k -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac sample.mp4");
```